# How to access a typecasted object's method directly?

Tags: java, oop, casting

This looks like a basic object oriented problem, but I was coming from Pascal / Delphi background, and I can't find the similar method to get the same result in Java.

In Pascal/Delphi, I can change something like this (this is not entirely correct, but just to give you an illustration):

```
var a: TButton; b: string;
begin
  a := TButton(getObject(request));
  b := a.caption;
end;
```

into this:

```
var b: string;
begin
  b := TButton(getObject(request)).caption;
end;
```

But how to achieve the same solution in Java? how to change:

```
Button a;
String b;
a = (Button) getObject(request);
b = a.caption;
```

into

```
String b;
b = (Button) getObject(request).caption;
```

or something like that? The point is, I want to eliminate the need of declaring temporary variable to hold an object, if what I want is just to take another value (or object) inside that object. But the problem is, the object need to be typecasted first because all I receive is just a general Object from the `getObject()` function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `b = (String)((Button) getObject(request).caption)`

Comment: I would post it as an answer so you can accept it

Comment: @DJClayworth done so, so you owe me a vote :)

Comment: I'll give it to you happily. Though it would be better with some explanation of why your version works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do as below:

```
b = (String)((Button) getObject(request).caption)
```

Comment: @DJClayworth depending on the context of use, you might need the String Cast to prevent noise from the compiler, example case is when the object `getObject` method is injected via some DI framework